# RaphaelJS in Ionic Framework: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, svg, ionic-framework, raphael

I am creating a mobile Apps using Ionic Framework. In this project, I am using Pathfinding.js and Raphael.js library to draw a path (using svg) in my navigation.html page.

My project structure looks like this:

www

js (folder)

- controllers.js (file)

  templates (folder)

  navigation.html (file)

index.html (file)

Inside index.html, it contains the following code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pathfinding-browser.min.js">    </script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Inside navigation.html, it contains the following code snippet:

```
 <div id="draw_area"></div>
```

In my controller.js, I have the following code snippet:

```
 var paper = Raphael("draw_area", 300, 300);
console.log("paper" + paper)
    var grid = new PF.Grid(120, 60);
    var finder = new PF.AStarFinder();
    var gridBackup = grid.clone();
    var path = finder.findPath(0, 0, 2, 2, gridBackup);

    var p1;
    var pathStyle = {
        stroke: 'yellow',
        'stroke-width': 3
    }



    var numRows = 100;
    var numCols = 120;
    var nodeSize = 10;
    var rects = [];
    grid.setWalkableAt(1, 0, false);

    executeTask();

    var nodeColorizeEffect = {
        duration: 50
    }



    function colorizeNode(node, color) {
        node.animate({
            fill: color
        },
            this.nodeColorizeEffect.duration);
    }

    function createRowTask(rowId) {
        rects[rowId] = [];
        for (j = 0; j < numCols; ++j) {
            x = j * nodeSize;
            y = rowId * nodeSize;


            rect = paper.rect(x, y, nodeSize, nodeSize);

            rect.attr("fill", "#f00");
            rect.attr("stroke", "#fff");
            rects[rowId].push(rect);
        }

    }

    function executeTask() {

        tasks = [];
        for (i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
            tasks.push(createRowTask(i));
        }
        drawPath(path);


    }

    function setStartEnd() {
        var coord = toGridCoordinate(5, 5)
        grid = this.grid
        var gridX = coord[0]
        var gridY = coord[1];


    }

    function drawPath(path) {
        if (!path.length) {
            return;
        }
        var svgPath = buildSvgPath2(path);
        this.path = this.paper.path(svgPath).attr(this.pathStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Given a path, build its SVG represention.
     */

    function buildSvgPath2(path) {
        var i, strs = [],
            size = this.nodeSize;
        var pathArray = " [ [M," + (path[0][0] * size + size / 2) + "," + (path[1][1] * size + size / 2) + "]"


        for (i = 1; i < path.length; ++i) {
            pathArray += ",[L," + (path[i][0] * size + size / 2) + "," + (path[i][1] * size + size / 2) + "]"

        }
        pathArray += "];"
        console.log(pathArray);
        return pathArray;

    }
```

However, this line of code, this.path = this.paper.path(svgPath).attr(this.pathStyle); gives me an error that says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined". I have tried many ways but could not solve the error.

**EDIT**:
It seems like the variable paper cannot find the id "draw_area" on the navigation.html.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Any help will be appreciated. Looking forward to your answer. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem today and the good new is that I brought the whole Raphael JS library into npm package. You can do "npm install raphael-pkg" and then import it to use. The package is available on https://www.npmjs.com/package/raphael-pkg.

Thanks.